# How to get selectedIndex of TabBarController, inside viewWillAppear?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have code inside my viewWillAppear method that requires checking the tab bar's selectedIndex. The only problem is, at this point its too early for the program to return the index, so I'm getting null.

Is there a way to access the selectedIndex without having to put the code inside viewDidAppear? I'm trying to resolve a visible 1 second flicker/delay load, which seems to only work in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to get it that I can think of. First, make the tabBarController a property of the appDelegate, and you can then get the appDelegate reference from the sharedApplication, then ask it for the UITabBarController object and ask it directly (or add a method to your appDelegate to provide the selectedIndex).

The second idea is to have a property on your viewController, just before its pushed (whatever) the selectedIndex is set.